# SlidingPaneLayout does not slide

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, slidingpanelayout

The slidingPaneLayout does not slide!

pane.isSlideable() is **false**!
I inflate the layout in this way:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                // Inflate the layout for this fragment
                slidingView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.available_nodes_fragment, container, false);


                SlidingPaneLayout pane = (SlidingPaneLayout)slidingView.findViewById(R.id.sliding_pane_layout);

                Fragment fragmentA = new ListNodesFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.add(R.id.child_fragmentA, fragmentA );

                Fragment fragmentB = new ReserveNodesFragment();
                transaction.add(R.id.child_fragmentB, fragmentB);

                transaction.commit();

                //pane.setPanelSlideListener(new SliderListener());
                pane.openPane();
                Log.i("Available Nodes","PANE IS SLIDABLE" + pane.isSlideable());

                return slidingView;

}
```

The **available_nodes_fragment** layout that i inflate is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_pane_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


         <LinearLayout
          android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
           <FrameLayout
          android:id="@+id/child_fragmentA"
          android:layout_width="180dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_gravity="left" />

           <FrameLayout
         android:id="@+id/child_fragmentB"
         android:layout_width="100dp"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_gravity="right" />
         </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>
```

I do not know why the SlidingPaneLayout does not slide. I do not know if this problem has to do with the fact that i use nested fragments.

---

I have some progress.

I changed the **available_nodes_fragment** layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/reserve_nodes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

      <android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/sliding_pane_layout"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/child_fragmentA"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"           
            android:background="#A588DC" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/child_fragmentB"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="#B6D4D3"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />

      </android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>


        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btnReserveNodes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:text="Reserve"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, the SlidePaneLayout layout slides. I do not know why. When i changed the fixed layout_width of the FrameLayouts to wrap_content, the SlidePaneLayout started to slide.

My problem now is that i want the FrameLayout with id= **"child_fragmentA"** with the ListView  to get the **30%** of the screen horizontally. I did not found a way to do it, since FrameLayout does not support weights.

I also provide the code of ListNodesFragment and ReserveNodesFragment.

**ListFragments.java**

```
public class ListNodesFragment extends Fragment {



     @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         View listNodesView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nodes_categories_listview, container, false);

         String[] items = { getResources().getString(R.string.orbit_nodes),
            getResources().getString(R.string.grid_nodes),
            getResources().getString(R.string.usrp_nodes),
            getResources().getString(R.string.diskless_nodes), 
            getResources().getString(R.string.icarus_nodes) ,
            getResources().getString(R.string.base_station)
          };

         ListView nodesListView = (ListView) listNodesView.findViewById(R.id.nodes_list);

         ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.nodes_categories_listview_item, items);
         nodesListView.setAdapter(adapt);
         return listNodesView;


     }

}
```

**ReserveNodesFragment.java**

```
public class ReserveNodesFragment extends Fragment {


     @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View reserveNodesView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reserve_nodes_fragment, container, false);
              TextView txtView = (TextView) reserveNodesView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
              txtView.setText("fragment 2");
            return reserveNodesView;
       }


}
```

Comment: Show your full activity code